# CSS/HTML Dropdown Menu appears left instead of below parent on Chrome, Edge, but not Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

The menu works properly, appearing below the parent item with the correct padding and margin adjustments for visual clarity. On Chrome and Edge it appears all the way to the left. I've looked at reseting margin and padding, but I either can't find the right place in the code to reset or it's not the problem. I've also looked at the different elements that are set to relative with similar (non)results.

HTML

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/books/">Books</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="/vladvir/">The World of Vladvir</a>
   <ul class="drop-nav">
    <li><a href="/locations/">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pronunciation/">Pronunciation Guide</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="/about/">About</a>
   <ul class="drop-nav">
    <li><a href="/about/">The Author</a></li>
    <li><a href="/barhamink/">Barham Ink</a></li>
    <li><a href="/the-site/">The Site</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.main-nav {
  font-family: Quattrocento Sans;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: green;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

  .main-nav,
  .drop-nav {
    background: green;
  }

  .main-nav > li {
    display: inline;
  }

  .main-nav li:first-child {
    display: inline;
  }

  .main-nav a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

.dropdown {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.drop-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
  .drop-nav a {
    font-size: .8em;
    margin-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .drop-nav li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
  }

    .drop-nav li:first-child {
      margin-top: 6px;
      display: block;
    }

    .drop-nav li:last-child {
    }

  .dropdown:hover > .drop-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }
```

And a JSFiddle that exhibits the behavior when switching between Safari and Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/NateBarham/st9tuLa3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.main-nav > li {
            display: inline;
          }
```

to

```
.main-nav > li {
            display: inline-block;
          }
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/st9tuLa3/2/

Comment: That fixes the problem. Thanks so much! I'm a beginner with all of this, and spent an embarrassing amount of time reading, changing lines, searching here and other answer sites before asking.

Comment: Welcome.  Glad your problem is fixed.  Kindly mark the answer so others can know...